# sessionStorage data not persist in AngularJS app with ngStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage, angular-services

All,

I'm simply trying to store a user object in sessionStorage in an AngularJS app. If I step through this in either the Chrome or FF debugger, the sessionStorage never gets set. Here is my angular service code:

```
// Authentication/authorization Module
stonewall.authModule = angular.module("authModule", [
    // Module dependencies
    "ngStorage"
    ]);

// Authentication/authorization service tracks the current user
stonewall.authModule.service('authService', function ($localStorage, $sessionStorage) {

    // Initialize current user
    var currentUser = {};
    restoreSession();

    // Declare storage type-this may change if user selects
    // "Keep me signed in"
    var storageType = {};

    // Return the current user object
    this.getCurrentUser = function () {
        return currentUser;
    };
    // Returns whether there is a currently authorized user
    this.userAuth = function() {
        return currentUser.sid != "";
    };
    // Logout function, initializes the user object
    this.logout = function() {
        currentUser = {
            sid: "",
            status: 0,
            pswLastSet: 0,
            id: "",
            sigUID: "",
            sig: ""
        };
        //persistSession();
    };
    // Login
    this.login = function(user, subj) {
        if (user == null) return;
        currentUser = {
            sid: user.Principal.SId,
            status: user.Principal.ControlStatus,
            pswLastSet: new Date(user.Principal.PasswordLastSet),
            id: user.Identity.Id.DN,
            sigUID: user.Identity.Certificates[0].UID,
            sig: stonewall.hash(user.Principal.SId + subj.pswd),
        };
        persistSession();
    };
    // Persist to session storage
    function persistSession() {
        $sessionStorage.currentUser = currentUser;
    };
    // Restore session
    function restoreSession() {
        currentUser = $sessionStorage.currentUser;
        if (currentUser == null) {
            // Initialize to empty user
            currentUser = {
                sid: "",
                status: 0,
                pswLastSet: 0,
                id: "",
                sigUID: "",
                sig: ""
            };
        }
    };
});
```

And, here is a screencap that shows my FF debugging session. You can see that after persistSession is called that $sessionStorage has my user.

[image: Debugger]

But, if I switch over to the DOM inspector, sessionStorage has no items in it...

[image: DOM]

Any help is, as always, appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are using angular's sessionStorage in the right way? 
Session storage is a property of the $window object in angular, so I don't know if you have made your own service wrapper or something like that?
Anyway, here is a codepen that shows another approach that I use myself, using $window.sessionStorage instead: http://codepen.io/chrisenytc/pen/gyGcx

Comment: Thanks feat, the changes you suggested worked. I was trying to use [this library](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) and followed their plunkr examples. I'm new to html/js development, so I figured I hosed something up somewhere.

Comment: Youre welcome. I did in fact not see that you were using this module, but if it works now theres no need to use the module. The code provided did not indicate if you imported the module correctly. If you want assistance on this specific issue, you should upload all the code so we can inspect it. But again, if it works now, why bother :)